# how to import a text file into R as a character vector

Tags: r, string, vector, import

I would like to know if there's a simple command in `R` which already exists and would allow to import a char text file (.txt) into a char vector.

The file might be English text with a string
like `"Hello my name is Fagui Curtain"`
and the output in R would be a char vector A
such that `A[1]<-"H"`, `A[2]<-"e"`, `A[3]<-"l"`, etc....

I've tried with the scan function, but it would return words
`A[1]<-"Hello"`, `A[2]<-"my"`....

I googled for my question but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks

Comment: You might try reading as 'raw' and converting indexed locations to 'character'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `strsplit` after removing the space with `gsub`

```
A <- strsplit(gsub('\\s+', '', lines),'')[[1]]
A
#[1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" "m" "y" "n" "a" "m" "e" "i" "s" "F" "a" "g" "u" "i" "C"
#[20] "u" "r" "t" "a" "i" "n"
```

Or

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(lines, '\\w')[[1]]
#[1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" "m" "y" "n" "a" "m" "e" "i" "s" "F" "a" "g" "u" "i" "C"
#[20] "u" "r" "t" "a" "i" "n"
```

Or if you are using linux, `scan` and be piped with `awk`

```
scan(pipe("awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"\";OFS=\" \"}{$1=$1}1' file.txt"), 
                  what='', quiet=TRUE)
#[1] "H" "e" "l" "l" "o" "m" "y" "n" "a" "m" "e" "i" "s" "F" "a" "g" "u" "i" "C"
#[20] "u" "r" "t" "a" "i" "n"
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
```

Comment: I think what they are looking for is as basic as `readLines(file)` and then `strsplit` and friends.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, I modified the post to read it from file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with use of `stringr` package (I like it as it produces very readable syntax).

***sample_text***

```
Hello my name is Fagui Curtain
```

***File reading***

```
require(stringr)
testVector <- str_split(readLines("sample_text.txt"), pattern = " ")
```